# Home button best practices

Tags: buttons, homepage, pricing

I'm building a hosting company, there are buttons on the homepage that links to my main products, example:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjmspu.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Now, I really don't know if I should link this button to "Google Adwords -> Overview", or "Google Adwords -> Plans" straight away... Take a look at those pages:

## Overview

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDaeY0.png)</sup>

The advantages page contains some persuasive arguments, showing how Google Adwords can help his business. But I don't know if most people reads it, even though the text and images are well balanced

## Plans

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqTfCR.png)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you have obvious buttons on your homepage that lead to both the Overview and the Plans. "From $299" is not a call to action, so as a user I may not be really sure what I'm going to get. Better to have buttons like...

- "Learn more about our advertising" (links to Overview)
- "View Plans and Sign up" (links to Plans).

Answer (score 0):

I strongly prefer the overview because IMO if your audience needs an explanation about how marketing on Google works, you're going to want an overview page to spell things out for them before pushing pricing options to them.

Edit: The primary button should definitely be pointed towards the sale. I would make the Advantages link a smaller alternative CTA button in the shadow of the Pricing page.

[image: CTA example]

Comment: You always want to tell people why they want a product first before you tell them how much it costs, especially when dealing with such high cost products. If you start right off with "this is $299/month!" users may get scared away, even if the great features are listed on the same page. But, if you sell them on a product first and get them into the mindset of already thinking "Wow! I really want this product!", then the price tag may be more palatable.